How to convert datetime64[ns] with multiple timezones to UTC
I have a dataframe with two columns, the first one has a date and time (type: datetime64[ns]) and the second column has the timezone that it is in. I cannot figure out how to convert each of the times to UTC based on their individual timezone.

The straightforward one, use apply on rows.

If your date column is already of type datetime64[ns], use apply on axis=1 to localize it in the timezone in the second column and convert to UTC:
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2020-01-01"], "tz": ["EST"]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df["date_utc"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row["date"].tz_localize(row["tz"]).tz_convert("UTC"), axis=1
)

        date   tz                  date_utc
0 2020-01-01  EST 2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00


This works well. However, I am now getting an error that some of my dates are ambigous. Is there a way to change this so that I can set ambigous=True if the month if the month is larger than June and False if it is June or less?

It depends. Can you edit your question to include a reproducible example that raises this error?

This is the code I am using:
df['datetime_arr_utc']=df.apply(lambda row: row['datetime_arr'].tz_localize(row['zone_arr'], ambiguous=True).tz_convert('UTC'), axis=1)
And the error is:
NonExistentTimeError: 2024-03-31 02:45:00
If I set Ambiguous to False, then there will be other dates that will give the NonExistentTimeError. Having a conditional Ambifous parameter should resolve it.

I can't reproduce your error. If you edit your question or post a new one with a minimal reproducible example I may be able to help, otherwise there isn't much that I can add.

Turns out it was an issue with my underlying data. Once I fixed that your solution works well.
